# Add property note from javascript Enterpreise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have some code and i want to create `Property Note`

```
 var metric as EA.Element;
 metric = thePackage.Elements.AddNew("", "Text");
```

What i should put instead of `Text` to add what i want?

I tried:

```
 metric = thePackage.Elements.AddNew(text, "Property Note");
```

or

```
 metric = thePackage.Elements.AddNew(text, "PropertyNote");
```

**Edit:**

```
 metric = thePackage.Elements.AddNew(text, "Note");
```

does not work:

I am expecting

[image]
in the red box, not the `element` above it.

**Answer:**

```
 metric = thePackage.Elements.AddNew("", "Text"); // the Note Property
 metric.SubType = 18; // This will actually make a simple Text behave as Note Property
```

Comment: you want a note element or the note property of an element?

Comment: @Mart10 i want to add [this](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12/modeling_basics/addpropertiesnote.html) from the code

Comment: This is a bit tricky. I'll come up with an answer later the day.

Comment: @ThomasKilian looking forward to it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As promised here's the code to create a Diagram Note. Sorry for the Perl, but you'll likely be able to translate this to Javascript.

```
my $p = $rep->GetPackageByGUID("{157B01A5-8F9A-4458-8C7F-E48F5DA77B0A}"); # sample package
my $dnote = $p->Elements->AddNew("", "Text"); # the Note Property
$dnote->{SubType} = 18; # This will actually make a simple Text behave as Note Property
$dnote->Update(); # save in package elements
my $dia = $p->Diagrams->GetAt(0); # sample diagram
my $do = $dia->DiagramObjects->AddNew("l=10;r=110;t=-20;b=-80", ""); # place Note Property in diagram (coordinates are about top left)
$do->{ElementID} = $dnote->ElementID; # link with the Note Property
$do->Update(); # place in diagram
$rep->ReloadDiagram($dia->DiagramID); # make ir appear instantly
```